# switch small DC voltage with 90v. 30hz AC signal

Tags: ac, dc, interface, telephone

I need to momentarily activate an approx. 50mA @ 24V DC load, using a 90V, 30hz AC signal line. Whatever method is used, it needs to have the smallest current draw from the signal line possible.

I am not sure if it is possible to turn on a transistor or solid state relay with AC, and I cannot seem to find much on the web.

Comment: how long is momentarily?

Comment: Is this "do something when telephone rings?"

Comment: Is this a telephone ringing indicator? There are many ICs designed to do precisely this.

Comment: I knew 90V 30Hz AC sounded familiar. But I took the chance that someone had actually an interesting high voltage circuit to design :D

Comment: Sorry for the letdown, Gustavo, I realize this isn't terribly interesting as an academic exercise. However, as mundane as it is I would still love any help I can get. 

As to the other replies, yes it is a ringing indicator of sorts. I work in a manufacturing plant and we have a central telephone system, with 3 or more universal telephone alarms in the back half of the building. The reason for my question is that every time the phone rings, the load of the 3 alarms is too great for the central system and it overloads, thus I am looking to remove the load that line sees. 

@Dave, which IC's?

Comment: @Scott could you edit your question to reflect this then?

Comment: Smallest current possible isn't a good requirement. Do you have a goal you are trying to meet?

Comment: It's been a long time since I needed a standalone ring detector; usually I'm working with SLIC chips that have it built in. One example is the TI [TCM1520A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scts005b/scts005b.pdf).

Comment: @BrianCarlton: An [REN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringer_equivalence_number) of 1 represents a 7K load, or about 13mA @ 90V. The OP probably wants to stay below REN=0.3, or about 4mA.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that IC looks perfect! trouble is, I can't seem to find it anywhere as it appears to be obsolete. @Dave, do you know of any alternatives or equivalents? Also yes, I would like to keep the REN around what you suggested, as my current load is about 1.4 per device.

Answer (score 1):

I see from the comments so far that this circuit requirement is for a telephone ring detector circuit. There is a plethora of information on the web for telephone ring detector circuits. I suggest that you use a circuit that incorporates an opto-coupler to isolate the telephone line from what ever circuit that is used to drive the down wind ringers. The reason for this is that if you directly couple a phone line to circuits that are locally powered you can end up getting a lot of line frequency feedback into the phone line which is not a good thing. Here is one circuit that looks like it could be a good starting place for you.

[image]

Comment: This is a bad answer for several reasons. First, it loads the line way more than necessary. Second, the output specification was 24VDC @ 50mA. Finally, this circuit turns the output OFF when the phone rings!

Comment: I take back the comment about excessive load -- it's probably OK in that respect, but the other two comments stand.

Comment: I will give this a try if I cannot locate any single chip solutions. Just don't want this getting overly complicated :)

Comment: @Tweed - I presented this circuit as a starting point for Scott and stated so in my amswer. Your comment about the state of the relay only applies to what is happening to the current in the relay coil. The output can be connected to N.O. or to N.C. contacts to achieve the desired switching behavior. Your flippant comment about the load on the relay is just that. Since presented as a starting point is should be obvious that the relay can be used to drive almost any load. Nuff said.